Find the number of terms needed to reach a specified accuracy
Could you help me, the task is to determine the number of terms needed to sum up to reach accuracy of 5 decimal places. The series is: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$
I have seen that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, but this isn't excatly what I want but may be this will useful somehow, I don't have any good ideas how to start

The convergence is really slow, after 1000 terms you only get correct the first two terms

The error is the sum of the items that you didn’t add up. For example summing up to m, you didn’t add up 1/n^2 from m+1 upwards.
The error is the sum of 1/n^2 from m+1 to infinity, which is about the integral of 1/n^2, which is about -1/n from m to infinity, which is about 1/m.
So for five decimals you need to add up 100,000 terms. For say 10 digits you would have to be careful if you add the sum using floating-point arithmetic because of significant rounding errors.

Maybe you could loose all the "abouts" in your second paragraph... we just need an upper bound on the error.
$$\sum_{n=m+1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}< \int_m^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \frac 1m$$

I think you need to use programming to find $n$ such that condition satisfy. But as a help I made a simple desmos for you ,to find idea
enter link description here


You do not need any programing to show that $$\sum_{k+1}^\infty\frac 1{n^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(k+1)=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2
k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$

It is better if you get an error bound that does not depend on knowing the exact solution. Having the exact solution renders the exercise of computing partial sums useless.
